# Spring Boot could not find bean after dependencies updated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, gradle

The error I’m getting in my Spring Boot project is:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in brobot.elasticsearch.tests.TestElasticsearch required a bean of type 'io.github.jspinak.brobot.testingAUTs.StateTraversalService' that could not be found.
```

`brobot.elasticsearch.tests.TestElasticsearch` is a class in a Spring Boot application that tests the functionality of a Java library @ https://github.com/jspinak/brobot. The library class `StateTraversalService` is correctly annotated with `@Component`. In the test application, the library class imports show up without errors in the IDE.

This error showed up after I updated a number of dependencies in the *build.gradle* file. The reason I can’t go back to the old dependencies is that I need the updated *build.gradle* file for new functionality. I want to export logs from the library to an Elasticsearch container. Initially, I followed these instructions to set up Elasticsearch and Kibana containers with security: https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/getting-started-with-the-elastic-stack-and-docker-compose. The containers worked and I could access Elasticsearch from my terminal as well as from https://localhost:9200. However, I kept getting an https connection error despite having https specified in my configuration class.

In config class: `RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "https"));`
Elasticsearch log error: `received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection.`

I then bought a course online, downloaded the demo Spring Boot application, and followed the instructions to set up Elasticsearch and Kibana containers. It worked for the demo but not for my project. I still got the same https error message, despite having identical code for Elasticsearch and identical containers to the course demo. I then decided to update the dependencies to match those of the demo. This is when I got the *bean not found* error.

The project uses Java 20 and Gradle 8.4. I’ve specified Java 20 in 5 places in the Intellij IDE: *Settings*: (1) Gradle JVM, (2) Java compiler project bytecode version; *Project Structure*: (3) Project, (4) Modules, (5) SDKs

The matching dependencies in the test application and library have the same versions. Both test and library applications have the same Gradle and Java versions.

Here is the library's *build.gradle* file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '8.4'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'signing'
}

group 'io.github.jspinak'
version '1.0.7'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('com.sikulix:sikulixapi:2.0.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-nop'
    }
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic' 

    implementation 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.9.0'
    implementation "org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-core:1.0.0-M1"
    implementation "org.nd4j:nd4j-native-platform:1.0.0-M1"
    implementation 'com.github.kwhat:jnativehook:2.2.2'

    implementation 'co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:8.3.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'
}

java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

publishing ...
```

Comment: Can you provide some more java codes?The classes that you listed above

Comment: The library class StateTraversalService is here: https://github.com/jspinak/brobot/blob/main/library/src/main/java/io/github/jspinak/brobot/testingAUTs/StateTraversalService.java. I pushed the test application to Github just now: https://github.com/jspinak/spring-elastic-tests. I set up the test application to run the library's Spring configuration, which should communicate with the Elasticsearch container. The test application could call any class; the method it calls doesn't do anything in this context.

Comment: The classes ElasticClient https://github.com/jspinak/brobot/blob/main/library/src/main/java/io/github/jspinak/brobot/testingAUTs/configuration/ElasticClient.java and HttpClientConfigImpl https://github.com/jspinak/brobot/blob/main/library/src/main/java/io/github/jspinak/brobot/testingAUTs/configuration/HttpClientConfigImpl.java set up the connection to Elasticsearch. The Spring dependencies recognize the annotations on these classes and initiate the connection when setting up beans.

Comment: When the `org.springframework.boot` plugin is set to version 2.6.2, the application recognizes the library's beans. Later versions cause the `bean not found` error. Does anyone know why or how to fix this?